# how to give alt tag to image in a div so that boots can view it?

Tags: html, seo

Actually my code is like below.

```
<div id="logoSec"></div>
<style>
#logoSec {
    background-image: url("http://c.mtro.co/am/i/amlogo.png");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 66px;
    width: 100%;
} 
</style>
```

So I want to give ALT to the image. So how can I give that? So that boots can view it.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, if you want to give an image an alt attribute, you should use the img tag rather than creating a div with a background image. Like this:

```
<img src="http://c.mtro.co/am/i/amlogo.png" alt="Your alt text">
```

However, if this image is the company's logo (as it appears to be), I would recommend using an h1 element, and replacing the text with the image.  This is semantic and will be better understood by search engines.  It would look something like this:

#### HTML

```
<h1 class="logo">America's Mattress</h1>
```

#### CSS

```
h1.logo {
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url("http://c.mtro.co/am/i/amlogo.png") no-repeat center center;
  height: 66px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

You can read more about this image replacement technique here: [REPLACING THE -9999PX HACK (NEW IMAGE REPLACEMENT)](http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/)

Comment: A quick notice in your css code. It should be width, not with.